# Flask+Cloudinary upload error on pythonanywhere

Tags: python, web-services, flask, cloud, cloudinary

### **Hi everebody!**

Please help me, I'm stuck with cloudinary uploader error. 
The problem is that on localhost this function works well, but after deploying on pythonanywhere server it doesn't.
Use:

- - Python3.4

    - sqlite database

      - SQL Alchemy 1.1.4
    - Flask 0.11.1
    - cloudinary python module
    - flask-googlemaps module
    - httplib2 module
    - requests module

Bits of my Code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for, \
    flash, jsonify, make_response
from flask import session as login_session  # to avoid confusion with DB session
import random
import string
import httplib2
import json
import requests
import content
# Cloudinary API imports

import cloudinary
import cloudinary.uploader
from cloudinary.uploader import upload
import cloudinary.api
from cloudinary.utils import cloudinary_url


CLOUDINARY = {
  'cloud_name': 'ainsolence',
  'api_key': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
  'api_secret': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
}

cloudinary.config(cloud_name='ainsolence', api_key='xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
                  api_secret='xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx')

...

# Create route for editCategory function

# Create route for uploadCategoryImage function

@app.route('/catalog/<int:category_id>/edit/upload/', methods=['GET',
           'POST'])
def uploadCategoryImage(category_id):
    if 'username' not in login_session or login_session['email'] \
        not in ADMIN:
        return redirect('/login')
    catalog = session.query(Category).all()
    categoryToEdit = \
        session.query(Category).filter_by(id=category_id).one()
    upload_result = None
    image_url = None
    if request.method == 'POST':
        file = request.files['file']
        if file:
            try:
                upload_result = upload(file, use_filename='true',
                                       folder='Menin_zherim/Categories')
                print ('This is upload result ' + upload_result)
                (image_url, options) = \
                    cloudinary_url(upload_result['public_id'], format='jpg')
                print ('Image url = ' + image_url)
                categoryToEdit.image_url = image_url
                session.add(categoryToEdit)
                session.commit()
                flash('Image for category successfully uploaded!')
                return redirect(url_for('editCategory',
                                category_id=category_id, catalog=catalog,
                                title='Edit category'))
            except:
                flash('Error in uploading', )
                return redirect(url_for('editCategory',
                                category_id=category_id, catalog=catalog,
                                title='Edit category'))
    else:
        return render_template('uploadCategoryImage.html',
                               category_id=category_id,
                               catalog=catalog,
                               category=categoryToEdit,
                               title='Upload image category')

#In uwsgi file I put this:
#Cloudinary base url
os.environ["CLOUDINARY_URL"] = "CLOUDINARY_URL=cloudinary://blablablabla:XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX@ainsolence"
```

PS: of course I use real api_key and api_secret in my code

Error.log before I used try/except:

```
2016-12-20 07:37:01,224 :cloudinary.api.Error: Unexpected error - MaxRetryError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.cloudinary.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /v1_1/ainsolence/image/upload (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7fe1621bbc88>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused',))",)
2016-12-20 07:37:01,200 :Exception on /catalog/4/edit/upload/ [POST]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 142, in _new_conn
    (self.host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 98, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 88, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 595, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 352, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 831, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 254, in connect
    conn = self._new_conn()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 151, in _new_conn
    self, "Failed to establish a new connection: %s" % e)
urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7fe1621bbc88>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/Aintest/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/cloudinary/uploader.py", line 257, in call_api
    response = _http.request("POST", api_url, param_list, headers, **kw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/urllib3/request.py", line 73, in request
    **urlopen_kw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/urllib3/request.py", line 151, in request_encode_body
    return self.urlopen(method, url, **extra_kw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/urllib3/poolmanager.py", line 248, in urlopen
    response = conn.urlopen(method, u.request_uri, **kw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 668, in urlopen
    release_conn=release_conn, **response_kw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 668, in urlopen
    release_conn=release_conn, **response_kw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 668, in urlopen
    release_conn=release_conn, **response_kw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 640, in urlopen
    _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 287, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.cloudinary.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /v1_1/ainsolence/image/upload (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7fe1621bbc88>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused',))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1988, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1641, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1544, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 33, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1639, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1625, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/home/Aintest/menin-zherim/project.py", line 251, in uploadCategoryImage
    folder='Menin_zherim/Categories')
  File "/home/Aintest/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/cloudinary/uploader.py", line 36, in upload
    return call_api("upload", params, file=file, **options)
  File "/home/Aintest/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/cloudinary/uploader.py", line 259, in call_api
    raise Error("Unexpected error - {0!r}".format(e))
```

Error.log after:

```
    2016-12-20 08:40:04,836 :Starting new HTTPS connection (1): 

    api.cloudinary.com
2016-12-20 08:40:12,846 :Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7eff38c6dac8>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused',)': /v1_1/ainsolence/image/upload
2016-12-20 08:40:12,846 :Starting new HTTPS connection (2): api.cloudinary.com
2016-12-20 08:40:20,845 :Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7eff38c6dc88>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused',)': /v1_1/ainsolence/image/upload
2016-12-20 08:40:20,846 :Starting new HTTPS connection (3): api.cloudinary.com
2016-12-20 08:40:28,846 :Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7eff38c6dd68>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused',)': /v1_1/ainsolence/image/upload
2016-12-20 08:40:28,846 :Starting new HTTPS connection (4): api.cloudinary.com
2016-12-20 08:54:31,637 :Starting new HTTPS connection (5): api.cloudinary.com
2016-12-20 08:54:39,689 :Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7eff38c81c88>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused',)': /v1_1/ainsolence/image/upload
2016-12-20 08:54:39,690 :Starting new HTTPS connection (6): api.cloudinary.com
2016-12-20 08:54:47,689 :Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7eff38c81be0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused',)': /v1_1/ainsolence/image/upload
2016-12-20 08:54:47,690 :Starting new HTTPS connection (7): api.cloudinary.com
2016-12-20 08:54:55,689 :Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7eff38c81d68>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused',)': /v1_1/ainsolence/image/upload
2016-12-20 08:54:55,690 :Starting new HTTPS connection (8): api.cloudinary.com
```

Please help me, if you have any advices where I can find the answer or just how  I can understand this issue

Thank you
Best Regards
Anton

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're doing this from a free PythonAnywhere account, then you haven't configured the cloudinary library you're using to use the PythonAnywhere proxy for outgoing connections. The proxy details are `proxy.server:3128`.

Comment: THx too much! Yeah, the problem is that  they have "whitelist". In fact I was not able to solve the problem through the proxy settings (I tried bush export and uwsgi config and other), but now I realized what was happening. I'll look for other free hosting for testing my projects or use the paid.

Comment: So how do you configure this proxy details? Kindly give an example.